# Spring boot initializer dependencies list

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created an initialization using https://start.spring.io/ , but I forgot which dependencies I selected. What would be a simple way to tell?

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom.xml or build.gradle(.kts)